# PDO Get Last Inserted 'id'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've tried a few other answers but nothing seems to be working. Here is what I'm doing:

```
try {
    $dbo = new PDO("dblib:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db","user","password");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, address) values (:name,:address)";
$insert = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$insert->execute(array('name'=>'name val', 'address'=>'address val'));

echo $insert->lastInsertId();
```

The rows are inserted but I always get a blank value when what I want is the value of the column 'ID'.  How do I go about it?

Comment: Do you have a primary key in the table ?

Comment: Yes, 'ID' is the primary key

Comment: [`lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) is a method of *PDO*, not *PDOStatement*

Comment: add `$dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to get the *real* reason why it's failing.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it almost right.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, address) values (:name,:address)";
$insert = $dbo->prepare($sql);
```

The `$insert` field is a statement, not the PDO driver, which you can execute. That's an another instance. After its execution, you can request the last inserted ID. But you have to call this method with the driver object, not the statement.

```
$dbo->lastInsertId();
```

with this statement, you are asking the PDO driver to return the ID of the inserted row that you have inserted in a table.

Also, add `$dbo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to get the *real* reason why it's failing.

Comment: Still doesn't work with $insertid = $dbo->lastInsertId(); 
echo $insertid;  I get blank.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure that your table has a column 'id' with AUTO_INCREMENT.